# R - Loop to subtract each successive value from first in a series

Tags: r

I am tinkering around with this loop (im new to writing loops but trying to learn).

I am aiming when `x == 1`, on first 1 match, store the value of z, then on each successive z value subtract that z value from the first value. If `x == 0` then it will do nothing (not sure if i have to tell the code to do nothing when `x ==0`?)

```
This is my dummy data: 

x <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
z <- c(10,34,56,43,56,98,78,98,23,21,45,65,78)
df <- data.frame(x,z)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$x[i] == 1)
  first_price <- df$z[i]
  df$output <- first_price - df$z
  }
}
```

I have my `if (df$x == 1)`
Then I want to save the first price... so `first_price <- df$z[i]` 
The `i` in here, that means the first in the series right?

Then for my output... i wanted to subtract the first price from each successive price. If I fix the first price with [i] is this the correct way? And if I leave df$z would that then take the next price each time in the loop and subtract from 
`first_price <- df$z[i]`?

Heres a visual: 
[image]

******Progress****

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
+   if (df$x[i] == 1) {
+   first_price <- df$z[1]
+     df$output <- first_price - df$z
+     }
+ }
> df$output
 [1]   0 -24 -46 -33 -46 -88 -68 -88 -13 -17 -35 -55 -68
```

If i add `[1]` which is assigning the first element in df$z this actually fixes the first element and then subtracts each successive, now It needs to be rule based and understand that this is only to be the case when `df$x == 1`

Comment: can you please share the result that you do expect from this?? thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
ans <- df %>%
         mutate(originalrow = row_number()) %>%    # original row position
         group_by(rleid(x)) %>%
         mutate(ans = first(z) - z) %>%
         filter(x==1)

# # A tibble: 7 x 5
# # Groups:   rleid(x) [2]
      # x     z originalrow `rleid(x)`   ans
  # <dbl> <dbl>       <int>      <int> <dbl>
# 1     1    56           3          2     0
# 2     1    43           4          2    13
# 3     1    56           5          2     0
# 4     1    78           7          4     0
# 5     1    98           8          4   -20
# 6     1    23           9          4    55
# 7     1    21          10          4    57

vans <- ans$ans
# [1]   0  13   0   0 -20  55  57
```

**EDIT**

To keep all rows, and outputting 0 where x==0

```
ans <- df %>%
         mutate(originalrow = row_number()) %>%
         group_by(rleid(x)) %>%
         mutate(ans = ifelse(x==0, 0, first(z) - z))

# # A tibble: 13 x 5
# # Groups:   rleid(x) [5]
       # x     z originalrow `rleid(x)`   ans
   # <dbl> <dbl>       <int>      <int> <dbl>
 # 1     0    10           1          1     0
 # 2     0    34           2          1     0
 # 3     1    56           3          2     0
 # 4     1    43           4          2    13
 # 5     1    56           5          2     0
 # 6     0    98           6          3     0
 # 7     1    78           7          4     0
 # 8     1    98           8          4   -20
 # 9     1    23           9          4    55
# 10     1    21          10          4    57
# 11     0    45          11          5     0
# 12     0    65          12          5     0
# 13     0    78          13          5     0
```

Comment: K anyway to output along with the 0's or the original position?

Comment: I've edited my answer to keep original row postiions. The alternative, to keep the `0s`, you can leave out the last line `filter == 1` and remove the `%>%` preceding it

Comment: k we still need to execute only on x==1 only and keep original row positions.

Comment: This is not what your output shows. I'll edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: sorry that output was one of my failed attempts.

Comment: What should the output be for rows where `x==0`? I've placed your answer in a new column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154591/discussion-between-andrew-bannerman-and-cpak).